# Get the instance name of the EC2 instance on which the code is deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

I want to get the instance name of the instance on which the code is deployed in shell script and store it in a variable.

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info
```

I tried the above command and got a json output  which looked something like this:

```
{
"Code":"Success"
"LastUpdated":"date",
"InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:677.. /instance-name"
"InstanceProfileId" : "",
}
```

Reference: [Retrieve instance metadata - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

Now, I want to fetch the `InstanceProfileArn` and store it in a variable as this contains instance name. I want to use this for some other functionality.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the JSON to [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the value that you are interested in.  Use the `-r` option to make it output just the string value:

> --raw-output / -r:
>
> With  this option, if the filter´s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk  to  non-JSON-based  systems.

```
ARN=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info | jq -r .InstanceProfileArn`
```